# Sequelize count fn add where clause

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

The below code works fine, but i only want to count students who are present. how can i do that.

```
Classroom.findAll({
  attributes:{  
        include : [
          [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('student.id')), 'count'] // here.  where student.present = true;
        ],
      },
      include:  [{ attributes: [], model: Student, as : 'student', }], 
      group: [sequelize.col('Classroom.id')]
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add that condition in include model :

```
Classroom.findAll({
  attributes:{  
        include : [
          [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('student.id')), 'count']
        ],
      },
      include:  [
          { 
              attributes: [], 
              model: Student, 
              as : 'student', 
              where : { present : true } // <--------- HERE
            }
        ], 
      group: [sequelize.col('Classroom.id')]
})
```

Comment: what if i also want total count of students. ('presentCount' & 'totalCount').

Comment: then you can try `group: [sequelize.col('Classroom.id'),sequelize.col('student. present')]` and remove  where condition, this might throw error and for that you have to add attributes in include students model

Comment: @farhanlatheef, sorry I can't as I dont know what error it will throw , then it will become trial and error, you will post each error and I will solve one by one, I can' test your scenario as I don't have DB or platform to test.